# FindResource() doesn't find my resource

Tags: c, winapi

I have some code template that i compiled, i would like to understand one part of the code that i am can't figure out what it does although i have spent a whole day tried to.

the code in question is as follows:

```
#define IDR_STUB 1
hRsrc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_STUB), "STUB");
```

I have another two files in the same directory as the main file, the first one is called `something.rc' and is content is:

```
#define IDR_STUB 1
IDR_STUB STUB DISCARDABLE "stub.exe"
```

The other file as you can guess is `stub.exe`.

My question is what is wrong with the `FindResource` call above that it can't find whatever is trying to find, I have hard time to understand how that function is suppose to work.

So if you can give me some help i would be glad :)

THX.

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` report after the failed to call to `FindResource()`?

Comment: Hmm Im not very sure but as far as I remember .rc should be first compiled to .res in order to make it work, which can be done with rc.exe

Comment: And then link it into the final binary.

Comment: could you please add some explanation about the `FindResource` function here ?

Comment: Info on FindResource : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @stupid_idiot and @hmjd , THX it is working now, the problem was that i didn't made the .res file, and after including it in the res directory under Visual C++ it compiled it as part of the exe, and the exe was able to find the resource. so the `FindResource` is correct.

Comment: @rkosegi you should read my question carefully before commenting, since i have read that right at the start of my research. I am asking for explenation on the resource (.res or .rc) files.

Comment: @Hanan N I expect your level is enough to know that res file must be linked to use resource functions...

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. I solved it by using string resource id as described in MSDN:

> If the first character of the string is a pound sign (#), the remaining characters represent a decimal number that specifies the integer identifier of the resource's name or type. For example, the string "#258" represents the integer identifier 258.

So try the following code:

```
hRsrc = FindResource(NULL, "#1", "STUB");
```

Comment: @rkosegi: No, MAKEINTRESOURCE is just a type cast.

Comment: Any idea which cases require this approach instead of MAKEINTRESOURCE?

Comment: @sgryzko Nope. I didn't dig into this.

Answer (score 1):

I've stuck in the same issue, when tried to use predefined resource type `RC_DATA`.

```
FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(name), RT_RCDATA);
```

This code was returning `NULL` whatever I did.

So when you edit your `.rc` file you should use constant `RCDATA`, but when you call `FindResource()` you should use constant `RT_RCDATA`. Be careful. Hope I've helped someone.